# Niederreiter cryptosystem

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, niederreiter

I can't understand how [Niederreiter cryptosystem](https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.07.022/2015_spring/uploads/Main/sander-report-s15.pdf)
works. If $c=mH^{'T}$ than why we cannot compute $m$ directly by multiplying $c$ with the $(H^{'T})^{-1}$? Can you give me an example of a "fast decoding algorithm"?

Thank you!

Comment: did you consider the noise removal by $D$?

Comment: What noise? That's confuses me. In the McEliece cryptosystem we add some error $e$ but in all Niederreiter documentations I didn't see any error adding to the plaintext message

Answer (score 1):

In the Niederreiter system, the plaintext is mapped to some error vector of weight $t$, where the code correction capability is $d=2t+1.$

With the trapdoor information (permutation) this can be decoded by the legitimate receiver by syndrome decoding.

Without the trapdoor information, this is equivalent to decoding a random vector, which is hard, as in the McEliece cryptosystem.

Comment: Is $2t+1$ excessive?

Comment: It is always guaranteed that the matrix H' doesn't has an inverse?

Comment: @kelalaka If you took $d=t+k+1$ you might be unlucky and the actual codeword might only be Hamming distance $k+1$ away which can be found with $O(2^{k+1})$ effort.

Comment: $H'$ is rectangular, so has no inverse.

Comment: Can be uniquely and correctly found?

Comment: In some cases, yes. The essential sphere packing radius is now $\lfloor (t+k)/2 \rfloor$ and by binomial coefficient properties there are exponentially more points on the surface of a sphere than further inside. We might as well then define $t'=\lfloor (n+k)/2 \rfloor$ as our correct security parameter giving $d=2t'+1.$

Answer (score 0):

Since the parity check matrix H' is not squared (it has dimensions $n-k \times n$), one can not ouput the message $m$ from the ciphertext $c$.

Nevertheless, there is an attack named [Lee-Brickell](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45961-8_25), which defines the security McEliece, but was later found that [can also be adapted to Niederreiter](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/13248374.pdf), showcasing the equivalence in security of both cryptosystems. The Lee-Brickell attack is based on extracting a full rank submatrix $H_{n-k} \in \mathbb{F}_2^{n-k \times n-k} $ which can be inversed so that the message is find randomly in a much smaller configuration space in $\mathbb{F}_2^{k}$.